# Syntax in case of calling class method via pointer defined in that class

Tags: c++

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        fp = &A::f;
    }

    void (A::*fp)();

    void f()
    {
        cout << "A::f()" << endl;
    }
};
```

In main function, I have object of class A defined, and I would like to call a.fp(). However, I found out that I cannot do this neither with `a.fp()` nor with `(a.fp)()`. Finally, `(a.*a.fp)()`, which is totally strange from syntax point of view, worked.

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    (a.*a.fp)();

    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody explain what `(a.*a.fp)()` actually means and why `(a.fp)()` doesn't work?

Comment: You need to access `a` twice - once to get `a.fp` and second time to call `fp` on a given A instance (also `a` in your example).

Answer (score 5):

Let's add parentheses to make the grouping explicit:

```
( a.*(a.fp) )()
```

1. `a.fp` is a regular access to the pointer-to-member `fp` inside `a`.
2. `a.*(...)` retrieves the member function via indirection, using the pointer to member access operator.
3. `(...)()` performs the function call on the "callable" expression in `(...)`.

As to why `(a.fp)()` doesn't work. It's because pointers to members are not like regular pointers. You need to apply them to an object, an instance of the class. So `a.fp` only retrieves the pointer-to-member, which is not a callable type on its own. You can't call it without applying to an object, what is achieved by `.*` to produce a callable expression.

Answer (score 1):

This code accesses the `a` object in two different ways, for two different purposes. To understand it better, you need to separate the two.

Calling a member function through a pointer-to-member-function requires either `.*` or `->*`, depending on whether you have an actual object or a pointer to an object:

```
void (A::*afp)() = &A::f;
A a;
(a.*afp)();  // calls A::f on the `a` object
A* ap = &a;
(ap->*afp)() // calls A::f on the `a` object
```

When the pointer-to-member-function is a member of the class you have to access the pointer with the usual class member access. That is, `a.fp` is the pointer-to-member-function in the object `a`. So, combining the two, `(a.*a.fp)()` calls the member function of `a` that `a.fp` points at, and calls it on the `a` object.

Answer (score 1):

`a.fp` is a pointer to a member function, where "pointer" is to be understood in the very general sense of "some kind of indirection based on an object".
The pointer has no knowledge about any instance of `A` - you need an object that it can be "dereferenced" relative to.
That is, you also need `a`.

Dereferencing any member pointer `p` relative to `a` looks like `a.*p`.
 (`.*` looks like two operators, but it's actually just one, the "pointer-to-member dereference operator").
Since your member function pointer is `a.fp`, the dereferencing syntax is `a.*(a.fp)`, or more condensed, `a.*a.fp`.

Then you need to wrap that bunch in parentheses (for precedence reasons) and you get

```
(a.*a.fp)()
```

Side note: the following are also valid:

```
void (A::*function)() = &A::f;
A a;
(a.*function)();
A b;
(a.*b.fp)();
```

and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
(a.*a.fp)();
    a          the instance a
    a.fp       the member of a which is a pointer to member function
   *a.fp       dereferencing the member function pointer
(a.*a.fp)()    invoking the member function on a
```

The last two steps are actually one (`.*` is one operator). In general if `mem_fun` is a member fucntion pointer the syntax to call it is

```
(a.*mem_fun)();
```

See also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access).